# Centripetal force and change of the tangential velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

I'm studying physics in the fifths semester and I'm still confused by some aspects of circular motion. So, I understand that the centripetal force changes the direction of the velocity, whereas the speed stays the same. But when the direction of the velocity changes, what causes the change of the tangential velocity at the uppermost point of the vertical circle ( since the tangential velocity has its direction in horizontal as well as in perpendicular direction as in the picture below )? Because obviously it has to change but the only applied force is the centripetal force, which does not "interact" with the tangential velocity. [image]

Comment: It looks like you are essentially saying "I understand the centripetal force changes the direction of velocity, but what causes the change in the direction of the velocity?" You recognize the tangential velocity only changes direction (for uniform circular motion), and you recognize this is caused by the centripetal component of the net force. So I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I got it wrong. I mean, the centripetal force accelerates the body and therefore gives it new velocity - component perpendicular to the tangential velocity. But since the speed stays the same, the tangential velocity must decrease. So does the centripetal force "take" a piece of the tangential velocity and "give" it to the component perpendicular to it? For me it doesn't make sense, because the force is also perpendicular to the tangential velocity and therefore should not influence it.

Comment: Why do you think if the speed stays the same the tangential velocity decreases? In circular motion the velocity is only tangential, so constant speed means constant tangential velocity magnitude.

Comment: @Bababa Yes why should the tangential velocity change ? There is no other velocity than the tangential velocity otherwise if it existed the body will not fly off tangentially if the force is removed rather would take the path obtained by the resultant of the two velocities.

Comment: Yeah both of you are absolutely right. Well, consider a circle and a particle on top of the circle. Then the vector of the velocity is parallel to the ground. Just a moment later, the velocity has a different angle. So when we brake the vector down in two components, namely one, which is parallel to the ground and one, perpendicular to it, the previous component parallel to the ground decreases. But, since the centripetal force is perpendicular to it, it should not change it. So, when I mentiones "tangential velocity", I meant the component parallel to the ground, I'm sorry!

Comment: Are you talking about a vertical circle?

Comment: Just an ordinary circle. I just used the ground as a reference for describing the angle.

Comment: Circles are circles. I'm not sure what the adjective "ordinary" means. I'm asking about the orientation of your circle. It sounds like it is vertically oriented if the angle with the ground can change. But I want to make sure, since you still aren't being very clear here, and you seem to be using terminology differently than it's usually used.

Comment: I'm sorry! I thought of exactly this situation: https://www.lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/scenario/centrip.htm (first image). And I broke the velocity vector down in two components.

Comment: The tangential direction is (what's in a name) tangential to the circle at the point that you are considering. Hence if the point moves, the tangential direction changes too. You can't simply keep projecting it on the same axis (the initial tangential direction in your case). I guess this is where your confusion arises.

Comment: @Bababa the actual motion of the body is along the tangent at each point and it is not changing. However it's components along the horizontal axis and the vertical axis changes in the first quadrant this doesn't mean that it's actual velocity changes . The one along the horizontal axis decreases and the one along vertical axis increases and when it reaches at the corner of the first quadrant it has only vertical component but it's magnitude is the same.

Comment: So, I'm very thankful for your help, but I think I can't communicate my problems.

Comment: @ankit Yeah but what causes the change of the horizontal velocity? The centripetal force only accelerates the body in terms of the vertical velocity...

Comment: @Bababa since  you are taking the components of tangential velocity on horizontal and vertical axis  then you should also take the components of centripetal force along the same horizontal and vertical axis. This will show you why horizontal component decreases and vertical increases in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Bababa was that helpful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some clarification. In circular motion, velocity is actually the same as tangential velocity, or in other words, there is no radial component of the velocity (otherwise it wouldn't describe a circle).

Now, a force produces an acceleration since $\vec{F}=m ~\vec{a}$, and an acceleration is a change of velocity in a given time interval. So the centripetal force does "interact" with the velocity (thus with the tangential velocity) because this force produces an acceleration $\vec{a}= \vec{F}/m$ which is $\vec{a} = \Delta \vec{v}/ \Delta t = (\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1)/\Delta t$.

$\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are vectors, so you have to subtract one from the other in vector fashion. Their speed does not change, but their direction does, so here the angle $\alpha$ and $\Delta t$ will enter into the equation.
Although space is 3-D, you might notice that this motion takes place in a plane, so you can ignore one of the 3 space coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a mass moving in a vertical circle on the end of a string, there are two forces acting: the tension in the string and gravity.  At the top of the circle, both are acting down and the tangential speed is not changing. (The sum of the two produces the centripetal acceleration.)  At any other point, gravity has a tangential component.  The tangential speed increases as the mass is coming down and decreases as it goes up.

Comment: No, I just thought of a isolated system, no forces at all (except the centripetal force). And now I'm wondering what causes the change in the horizontal component of vector 1?

Comment: If the object is moving in a horizontal circle, the change in the velocity vector during a very short interval of time is caused by the centripetal force and is directed toward the center of the circle. Keep in mind that the Δv on your vector diagram represents a vector sum of many small  Δv's which vary in direction.

Comment: just consider any  motion on a plane  along a line with constant velocity , than give it a small push perpendicular to the line, what will happen ?

Comment: If the only force is the centripetal force, then there is no change in the tangential speed.

Answer (score 0):

In general for any particle in circular motion, the net acceleration of the particle is

$a_{net} = \sqrt[]{a_r^2 + a_c^2}$

[image]

It can be seen that net acceleration is little off center. For the particles whose speeds do change some part of this acceleration modifies the tangential velocity, and other changed its direction.

Consider a simple example, a person is swinging a bob tied to a string horizontally. A careful look at his hand shows that his hand ( that is producing overall acceleration for the motion) is pull in the direction of $a_{net}$.

For cases where the circular motion is uniform, only tangential acceleration remains that is changing its direction.

$a_{net} = \sqrt[]{0^2 + a_c^2} = a_c$